# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentExceptioneason: '-[__NSCFDictionary Exercise]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, sigabrt

I'm new to xcode, I have this problem the app crashes giving me this error, when I try to tap a cell going to  DetailViewcontroller with error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary Exercise]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ca15b0'. I'm not sure what is the reason. I copied here the code:

MAsterViewcontroller.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController{

    NSMutableArray* routines_;
    NSMutableArray *routineinfo_;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray* routines;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray* routineinfo;

@end
```

the file MasterViewController.m

```
    #import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "ClassDetailViewController.h"
#import "ClassConstants.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize routines=routines_,routineinfo=routineinfo_;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad

    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mills" ofType:@"plist"];

        routines_= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        //Uncomment the following line to displa an Edit button in the navgation bar for this view controller.

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    }


    - (void)dealloc {
    [routines_ release];
    [routineinfo_ release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    //    if (!_objects) {
    //        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //    }
    //    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    //    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    //    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}



//Customize the number of rows in the table view.

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.routines count];

}


//Configure appearence of table view cells.


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.routines objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                       objectForKey:NAME_KEY];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        // Get the data given the selected row
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSInteger IndexSelected=[indexPath row];
        //NSDictionary *routinedata = [self->routines_ objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        // Pass that data on to the DetailViewController
        DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;


        NSString *pathSelected=@"";;


        switch (IndexSelected)

        {
            case 0:

                pathSelected = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mills0" ofType:@"plist"];

                break;

            case 1:
                 pathSelected = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mills1" ofType:@"plist"];

                break;

            case 2:
                  pathSelected = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mills2" ofType:@"plist"];

                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
         routineinfo_= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathSelected];

        detailVC.routineinfo = self.routineinfo;


    }
}



@end


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController{

@private
NSMutableArray *routineinfo_;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *routineinfo;


@end
```

ClassDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController{

@private
NSMutableArray *routineinfo_;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *routineinfo;


@end
```

ClassDetailViewController.m file

```
    #import "ClassDetailViewController.h"
#import "ClassConstants.h"
#import "MillsDetailsConstant.h"
#import "LesMillsCell.h"

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize routineinfo=routineinfo_;



- (void) dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
    [routineinfo_ release];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.routineinfo count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LesMillsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    LesMillsCell *LesMillsCell=self.routineinfo [indexPath.row];


    //Configure the cell EXERCISE
    LesMillsCell.Exercise.text= [[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                         objectForKey:EXERCISE_KEY];


    //Configure the cell SONG
    LesMillsCell.Title.text= [[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                         objectForKey:SONG_KEY];

    //Configure the cell ARTIST
    LesMillsCell.Artist.text= [[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                         objectForKey:ARTIST_KEY];

    //Configure the cell TIME
    LesMillsCell.Artist.text= [[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                       objectForKey:TIME_KEY];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}

//Configure appearence of table view cells.
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


 //setto  la sezione
 //   NSInteger nSection;
 // setto le righe per sezione
 //   NSInteger nRows;
 // nRows= [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];
    // creo una cella prptotypes per ogni riga della sezione
   // NSIndexPath IndexTableView



   // nRows=self.tableView
}

 @end
```

the Subclasses file LesMillsCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LesMillsCell : UITableViewCell{

@private

// UITableViewCell *lesmillscell_;
UILabel *Exercise_;
UILabel *Title_;
UILabel *Artist_;
UILabel *Time_;
NSMutableArray *routineinfo_;



}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Exercise;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Artist;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Time;





@end
```

LesMillsCells.m

```
#import "LesMillsCell.h"
#import "ClassConstants.h"
#import "MillsDetailsConstant.h"

@implementation LesMillsCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

thank you for you help!

Comment: Your crash on     LesMillsCell.Exercise.text= [[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                         objectForKey:EXERCISE_KEY]; this line right?

Comment: Can you please post NSDictionary that's insider routineInfo?

Answer (score 1):

If the crash occurs in this line:

```
LesMillsCell.Exercise.text= [[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:EXERCISE_KEY];
```

it means that LesMillsCell is not an object of LesMillsCell class, but NSDictionary (or __NSCFDictionary). So using Exercise on that object will cause error, because dictionary doesn't support that method. The error begins here:

```
LesMillsCell *LesMillsCell=self.routineinfo [indexPath.row];
```

self.routineinfo [indexPath.row] returns object of type id, so compiler is not able to know what type actually is that, so the assignment goes without warning.

Also, you are using routineinfo in two different ways. First you treat it as LesMillsCell

```
LesMillsCell *LesMillsCell=self.routineinfo [indexPath.row];
```

And a line below you treat it as dictionary, and extract value for EXERCISE_KEY:

```
[[self.routineinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                     objectForKey:EXERCISE_KEY];
```